# flask db init leads to "KeyError: 'migrate'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, migrate

I created already a database and added 2 tables (venue, artist).

This is a party from my app.py:

```
import json
import dateutil.parser
import babel
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler
from flask_wtf import Form
from forms import *
from flask_migrate import Migrate
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# App Config.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment(app)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# TODO: connect to a local postgresql database
##Done via the config file
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Models.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#Migrate
migrate =(app,db)
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venue'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    # TODO: implement any missing fields, as a database migration using Flask-Migrate
class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artist'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    genres = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

In my config file I create the connection.

If I try to run "flask db init" in the directory where also my app.py and all the other files are located I get the following error:

```
directory = current_app.extensions['migrate'].directory

KeyError: 'migrate'
```

I tried it for hours know but found no solution so far. What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 24):

I think you should add the code below:

```
migrate = Migrate(app, db) # this
```

For further info you can check this [link](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/196)

Comment: Oh damn! Missed it... THANKS

Comment: Just for clarity, in this example, `migrate = Migrate(app, db)` should be added to the app.py file. Make sure you have `from flask_migrate import Migrate` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can have this setup

```
"""App factrory file"""
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from app.config.config import APP_CONFIG
from app.db.database import db

def create_app():
    """App factory"""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(APP_CONFIG["development"])
    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app,db)

    # Register blueprint apps
    app.register_blueprint(homeViews)

    return app
```

Flask migrate must have the app instance injected together with the Sqlachemy instance
For environment variables you can have this in your `.env`

```
FLASK_APP=yourapp.py
FLASK_RUN_HOST="localhost"
FLASK_RUN_PORT=
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DB_USER=
FLASK_DB_PASSWORD=
FLASK_APP_SECRET_KEY=
```

For your `config.py`

```
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()


class DevelopmentConfig(object):
    """
    Development configuration just for local development
    """
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = f"postgresql://{environ.get('FLASK_DB_USER')}:\
        {environ.get('FLASK_DB_PASSWORD')}@localhost/db_name"
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class TestingConfig(object):
    """ Testing configuration just for local development"""
    ...


class ProductionConfig(object):
    """ Deployment configuration for production development"""
    ...


APP_CONFIG = {
    "development": DevelopmentConfig,
    "testing": TestingConfig,
    "production": ProductionConfig
}
```

Once you're done setting up you can running

```sh
>>> flask db init
>>> flask db migrate -m "Initial migrations"
>>> flask db upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask comand uses env variable  FLASK_APP, to know where Flask app is located. For your application you will have to set FLASK_APP=microblog.py, as goes in chapter 1.

**source** - https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1124925856/the-new-and-improved-flask-mega-tutorial)

RUS -
Помните, что flask команда полагается на переменную среды FLASK_APP, чтобы знать, где расположено приложение Flask. Для этого приложения вы хотите установить FLASK_APP=microblog.py, как описано в главе 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Migrate(app,db)` to your project and just run the `flask db migrate` command from outside the folder where your project is located and set the location of the flask app with:

On Windows-- `set FLASK_APP=/absolute/path/to/flask/app`
On Linux-- `export FLASK_APP=/path/to/app/from/current/location`
Then try `flask db migrate` and it should work just fine.